# QML Button exclusiveGroup property?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm unable to assign ExclusiveGroup to my checkable buttons.

```
ExclusiveGroup {
    id: group

    onCurrentChanged: {
        if(current != null) {
            console.info("button checked...no!")
            current = null
            //current.checked = false    <--- also this
        }
    }
}


            Column {
                width: parent.width
                spacing: 0

                Button {
                    id: btnScan
                    flat: true
                    text: qsTr("But1")
                    width: parent.width
                    checkable: true
                    exclusiveGroup: group
                }
                Button {
                    id: btnWhiteList
                    flat: true
                    text: qsTr("But2")
                    width: parent.width
                    checkable: true
                    exclusiveGroup: group
                }
}
```

The documentation states clearly that Button does have exclusiveGroup property http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html#exclusiveGroup-prop. However, when I run the example, I get this error:

```
qrc:/main.qml:48 Cannot assign to non-existent property "exclusiveGroup"
```

Hovering mouse over "exclusiveGroup" makes a tooltip show up saying: "Invalid property name exclusiveGroup".

I have Qt 5.9.1 installed. Here's my import statements:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Material 2.2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason for your problem is this:

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
```

You have a `Button` in both, but they have a different API.
So at first you import the [`Button` from `QtQuick.Controls 1.4`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html). Then you import the [`Button` from `QtQuick.Controls 2.0`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-button.html). As QML doesn't know, which one you want to use, it will take the one, you imported the last. If you want to be more specific, on which `Button` you want to use, you can use *named imports*

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4 as OldCtrl
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 as NewCtrl
```

Then you can use `Button`s from both versions as you like:

```
OldCtrl.Button { // from the QtQuick.Controls 1.4 }
NewCtrl.Button { // from the QtQuick.Controls 2.0 }
```

The documentation you quote is for `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`, and from there is the imported `ExclusiveGroup`. So you are trying to mix things from two libraries, that wont work together.

See [**`ButtonGroup`**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-buttongroup.html) for a similar solution for `QtQuick.Controls 2.x`

For more on the differences and usecases of the both sets of controls read:

- http://blog.qt.io/blog/2016/06/10/qt-quick-controls-2-0-a-new-beginning/
- https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html

Comment: thats strange. but what should I do if I need properties defined in 2.0 as well? Isn't there a way to use all button properties defined in different versions?

Comment: Thanks, ButtonGroup did the trick and I accepted your answer. however, my confusion still remains on versioning. If you could help me clear things up I'd be very grateful :)